# jruby Bundler could not find compatible versions json

Tags: ruby, jruby, precompile

New to jruby.  I am getting error when trying to run

```
jruby -S bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "json":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    json (1.8.1)

  In Gemfile:
    carrierwave (>= 0) ruby depends on
      json (>= 1.7) ruby
```

I have tried removing Gemfile.lock and run "jruby -S bundle install", did not help.

I am using jruby 1.7.3 and ruby 1.8.7 on a Mac.  I have successfully run precompile before and have not made any changes to the Gemfile.

My Gemfile (has not been changed since last Oct., used to work):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'
gem 'jruby-openssl'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'carrierwave'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'bourbon'

  #gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyrhino'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'uuidtools'
gem 'amazon-ses-mailer'
gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your `Gemfile`?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a [bundler issue](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2780). Update Bundler to 1.5.2 and trying again:

```
jruby -S gem install bundler
```

Comment: thank you for the response.

I upgraded bundler to 1.5.2, and deleted Gemfile.lock. Now I am getting the following exception when running "jruby -S bundle install"

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...Exception in thread "JRubyWorker-2" org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (Result) Bundler::SafeCatch::Internal::Result
 at RUBY.throw(/usr/local/Cellar/jruby/1.7.3/libexec/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/safe_catch.rb:70)
 at ...

Comment: Now that's interesting. Reading the bundler source, it looks like you've hit a `throw` without a `catch`... could you re-run it as `DEBUG=1 jruby -S bundle install` and edit the whole stack trace into your question?

Comment: Thank you, Ash.  The log is quite long so I put it at http://pastebin.com/FHUu7HBV